# Symfony4 resource controller

Tags: api, symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I am developing an API under symfony4 and I wish I could create a parent controller that I could use to call functions that would be repeated in another controller. Here are my controllers that I would like to extend from a parent controller:

My DeliveryController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\DeliveryMan;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class AuthController
 * @package App\Controller
 * @Route("/api")
 */
class DeliveryController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route(
     *     name="api_delivery_man_post",
     *     path="/delivery_man",
     *     methods={"POST"},
     *     defaults={
     *         "_api_resource_class"=DeliveryMan::class,
     *         "_api_collection_operation_name"="post"
     *     }
     * )
     */
    public function postAction(DeliveryMan $data, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder): DeliveryMan
    {
        return $this->encodePassword($data, $encoder);
    }

    protected function encodePassword(DeliveryMan $data, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder): DeliveryMan
    {
        $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($data, $data->getPassword());
        $data->setPassword($encoded);

        return $data;
    }
}
```

My AuthController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

/**
 * Class AuthController
 * @package App\Controller
 * @Route("/api")
 */
class AuthController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route(
     *     name="api_users_post",
     *     path="/users",
     *     methods={"POST"},
     *     defaults={
     *         "_api_resource_class"=User::class,
     *         "_api_collection_operation_name"="post"
     *     }
     * )
     */
    public function postAction(User $data, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder): User
    {
        return $this->encodePassword($data, $encoder);
    }

    protected function encodePassword(User $data, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder): User
    {
        $encoded = $encoder->encodePassword($data, $data->getPassword());
        $data->setPassword($encoded);

        return $data;
    }
}
```

As can be seen I call 2 identical actions in 2 different controllers the only difference that there would be the entities and the path of the road.

So I was thinking of creating a ResourceController parent controller that would be extended from AbstractController and that the child controllers would be extended from ResourceController but I do not see how after how to create my methods in my parent controller and retrieve them in the child controllers.

If someone has already done that I am a taker :) Thank you for your help.

EDIT Result ResourceController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\DeliveryMan;
use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;

class ResourcesController extends AbstractController
{
    private $encoder;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;
    }

    public function encodePassword(User $data): User
    {
        $encoded = $this->encoder->encodePassword($data, $data->getPassword());
        $data->setPassword($encoded);

        return $data;
    }

    public function encodePasswordDelivery(DeliveryMan $data): DeliveryMan
    {
        $encoded = $this->encoder->encodePassword($data, $data->getPassword());
        $data->setPassword($encoded);

        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: So your controller is responsible for password management? You kill a panda each time you violate [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a ResourceController wich extends Symfony AbstractController.

Write your 2 shared methods here, then in any Controller that extends ResourceController you can call them as you would normally call a class method: using $this

```
class ResourceController extends AbstractController
{   
    private $encoder;

    public function __construct(UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder)
    {
        $this->encoder = $encoder;    
    }

    public function encodePassword(Object $data): Object
    {
        $encoded = $this->encoder->encodePassword($data, $data->getPassword());
        $data->setPassword($encoded);

        return $data;
    }
}

class AuthController extends ResourceController
{
    public function someAction(User $data)
    {
        return $this->encodePassword($data);
    }
}
```

I also suggest you write an interface with a getPassword method that User and DeliveryMan will implements. Not only you'll ensure that the method is implemented but you' also be able to typehint, say AuthenticatedEntityInterface, instead of Object

Comment: it works thx but cons I have to redo the same method in my controller resource 1 for User and 1 for DeliveryMan? (see my post)

Comment: You don't, you could have 1 method where $data parameter would be typed as 'Object' instead of one typed with 'User' and one with DeliveryMan but that's not ideal. Best here is to use OOP feature such as inheritance or interface, your DeliveryMan could be a child of User (maybe it's already the case ? ) then you could juste have 1 method typed with User. Or User and DeliveryMan could be children of AbstractUser and then type AbstractUser in your encodePassword. To work with interface, see my answer. Consider learning how OOP works as Symfony strongly relies on it.

Comment: Also, please consider upvoting / validating answer if it works for you, thanks :)